# Series convergence and limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve an exercise that asks me this:

Prove using the $ε–N$ method that the sequence

$a(n) = \frac{n^2 + n - 1}{n^2 + n}$

converges and state the limit.

My attempt is the following:

First, I guess that the $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} a(n) = 1$.

Then we require 
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
|a(n)-1| < ε &\iff \left| \frac{n^2 + n - 1}{n^2 + n} - 1 \right| < ε \\
&\iff \frac{1}{n^2 + n} < ε \\
&\iff \frac{1 }{ ε} < n^2 + n \\
&\iff n^2 + n > \frac{1}{ε}
\end{split}\end{equation}
Now, we take another number $2n^2$ which is greater or equal than $n^2 + n$ and say:

$2n^2 \geq n^2 + n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

$\implies 2n^2 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

$\implies n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2ε}}$

Therefore $N(ε) = \left\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}\right\rceil$

Is this correct? Can we just take another number greater than or equal to $n^2 + n$ and just continue to find the solution?

Any help is welcomed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2n^2 > 1/\epsilon$ will not guarantee $n^2+n > 1/\epsilon$.

You need to find a nice function of $n$, that lies between $n^2+n$ and $1/\epsilon$, which will allow you to solve for $n$ in terms of $\epsilon$. We can in fact choose $n>1/\epsilon$, since this will ensure that $n^2+n > 1/\epsilon$.

Comment: Can we do this? 

We don't know if n > 1/ε so how can we assume it?

On the other hand, if we know that n^2 + n > 1/ε

then we know that 2n^2 > 1/ε.

Comment: @ComputerN00b What do we want? We want $n^2+n$ to be greater than $1/\epsilon$. Hence, choosing $n>1/\epsilon$ will grant that. Choosing $2n^2>1/\epsilon$, **will not grant** $n^2+n$ to be greater than $1/\epsilon$

Comment: Ok I am getting you. So we say that n > 1/ε . And then we can say that N(ε) = ceiling (1/e) and that's it?